# Does the compiler optimize trivial getter methods into simple field accesses?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, methods, compiler-optimization, getter

While I would assume that in VC++ this would be a no brainer, it's still worth asking.

When creating a getter method for a class that *only* returns the value of a protected/private member, does the compiler optimize this call so it's the equivalent of referencing that member without having to friend the class and without the overhead of a full method call?

Comment: probably. just compile an example in VC++ w/ full optimization, but debugging symbols on, and set the break point at the function, and look at the assembly.

Comment: This has been the case for many years. In fact, you don't need to specify `inline` for simple methods defined inside the class. This is intentional, to keep simple getters simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Both variants compile to the same thing:

```
struct test
{
    int x;

    int get() const { return x; }
};

__declspec(noinline) int use_x(const test& t)
{
    return t.x;
}

__declspec(noinline) int use_get(const test& t)
{
    return t.get();
}

int main()
{
    test t = { 111605 };

    // pick one:
    return use_x(t);
    //return use_get(t);
}
```

Note that it's not as simple as always replacing `t.get()` with `t.x`, for the compiler. Consider something like this:

```
t.get() += 5;
```

This shouldn't compile, because the result of the function call is an rvalue and `+=` (for primitives) requires an lvalue. The compiler will check for things like that.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I needed to know.

Comment: int& x(void) { return x; }

foo.x() = 5;

Also compiles to foo.x = 5;